# How to install a specific kustomize version

Tags: macos, homebrew, kustomize

I am trying to install kustomize v3.2.1 in Mac, but I am getting the following error when I do these steps.

wget "https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/archive/refs/tags/kustomize/v3.2.1.tar.gz"
Untar the source

tar xzf xxxxx.tar.gz
cd xxxxxx
make install

Output:

```
go install /cmd/kustomize
make: go: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

How can I install this version without any issues? Thanks!

Comment: For others looking at installing Kustomize. The error above is because you don't have Golang installed on your mac.

Answer (score 8):

Just download this [script](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/hack/install_kustomize.sh) and then run:

```
./install_kustomize.sh [WANTED_VERSION]
```

Comment: + dont forget to copy it to the bin directories.

Comment: curl -s https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/hack/install_kustomize.sh | bash -s -- 4.5.7